# how to share List values in memory mapped files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0, memory-mapped-files

I have a windows form with datagridview and i'm reading particular column value into a list. I need to share all values of list in single memory mapped file  but below are my concern  :
1. Finding the size of list in bytes.
2. need to share all items of list.

here is my sample code where i'm sharing single variable value :

```
  string MyName = "Seema";
  int totalBytes = MyName.Length * sizeof(Char) + 4;
  public List<string> myList = new List<string>();

MemoryMappedFile MyText = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("MyGlobalData", howManyBytes);
                byte[] array1 = new byte[howManyBytes];
                array1 = GetBytes(Name);

                using (var accessor = MyText.CreateViewAccessor(0, array1.Length))
                {
                    accessor.WriteArray(0, array1, 0, array1.Length);
                }


 static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
```

assume mylsit has items 1. Apple 2. Mango 3. Pineapple

please guide how do i proceed with above code

Comment: Using one of many serializers (XML, JSON, binary,...) to create data to share feels much easier than re-doing it yourself... Can you please clarify what you trying to achieve by manually writing out each element?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using memory-mapped files? Are you communicating with other processes?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use locking (mutex) and will want to store the array size as the first element in the mmf.